# findAll fails after play morphia is reinitialised

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, morphia

I have the following class which is persisted into a mongodb using morphia in a play! application. The class resides in a module which is a dependency of another play! application.

Its configuration is read from a file and persisted into the db on initial load (if its not already in the db) and then subsequent requests use the db version.

```
@Entity
public class Page extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long navigationId;

    // etc ...
}
```

The initial load and subsequent query access works ok and i can see the page in mongo:

```
> db.Page.find({_id:20000})
{ "_id" : NumberLong(20000), "className" : "models.Page" etc }
```

However if i restart play! or make a code change that results in Morphia being reinitialised
(`MorphiaPlugin-1.2.4> initialized` appears in the logs) i get the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Error setting value from converter (LongConverter) for models.Page.navigationId to 20000
    at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:487)
    at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:267)
    at com.google.code.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.convertItem(MorphiaIterator.java:66)
    at com.google.code.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.processItem(MorphiaIterator.java:53)
    at com.google.code.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.next(MorphiaIterator.java:48)
    at com.google.code.morphia.query.QueryImpl.asList(QueryImpl.java:255)
    at play.modules.morphia.Model$MorphiaQuery.asList(Model.java:1067)
    at models.Page.findAll(Page.java)
    at plugins.PageConfigLoadPlugin.loadPersistedPages(PageConfigLoadPlugin.java:62)
    at plugins.PageConfigLoadPlugin.onApplicationStart(PageConfigLoadPlugin.java:51)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.onApplicationStart(PluginCollection.java:425)
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:495)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Error setting value from converter (LongConverter) for models.Page.navigationId to 20000
    at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.ValueMapper.fromDBObject(ValueMapper.java:27)
    at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:501)
    at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:484)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Error setting value from converter (LongConverter) for models.Page.navigationId to 20000
    at com.google.code.morphia.converters.DefaultConverters.fromDBObject(DefaultConverters.java:133)
    at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.ValueMapper.fromDBObject(ValueMapper.java:25)
    ... 16 more
```

If i drop the Collection from mongodb using the command line i can again load and query the Page obejct successfully from my play! web application

```
> db.Page.drop()
true
```

As I mentioned, this class is in a module. This problem only happens in one application that the module is a dependency of. The other demo application works fine.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Does the dependent module have another alternate declaration of the Page or
Model classes?

From the top of the stack trace, ("com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Error setting value from converter (LongConverter) for models.Page.navigationId to 20000"), it looks like there's a type mismatch between
the way a numeric value is being stored and retrieved.  For example, in Java,
it is not uncommon to store something as a Double and then mistakenly try
to retrieve it as an Integer or a Long.  So, can you verify that the
declaration of navigationId in the dependent module is the same as the one
you've shown here?  They should share the definition, but its possible there's
an alternate.

Another thing to check is that your code is putting a Long into your
DBObject and not a float.  For example, if you're inserting it via the shell,
you'll need to use one of the wrappers, e.g.

db.Page.save({_id:NumberLong(20000)});

Otherwise, this will also cause a mismatch when you retrieve it; by default
numbers in JavaScript are doubles.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Chris. There are no other declarations of Page in the classpath. Im pretty confident that the value is being saved correctly because retrieving it on the command line returns "_id" : NumberLong(20000) and the declaration in the class is Long navigationId.