# Play Morphia MappingException In WebSocket Iteratee After Reload

Tags: playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0, akka, morphia

I'm using Play 2.3 and Akka to set up a simple publish subscribe protocol over a web socket. As part of this protocol, after the client subscribes, the server sends the initial state from a database.

My current code works initially but, during development, the Morphia query inside the socket Iteratee stops working after a development reload. Regular requests, even requests that make the exact same query, continue to work fine.

I'm using the distributed pub sub mediator Akka plugin. Here's the relevant code for the actor representing the web socket listener:

```
object Subscriber {
  def props(channel: Concurrent.Channel[JsValue]): Props = Props(new Subscriber(channel))
}

class Subscriber(channel: Concurrent.Channel[JsValue]) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case StatusUpdate(...) =>
      channel.push(...)
  }
}
```

And for the main view controller:

```
object SocketController extends Controller {
  val mediator = DistributedPubSubExtension.get(Akka.system).mediator

  def index = WebSocket.using[JsValue] { implicit request =>
    val (out, channel) = Concurrent.broadcast[JsValue]

    val ws = Akka.system.actorOf(Subscriber.props(channel))

    val in = Iteratee.foreach[JsValue] { msg =>
      (msg \ "type").as[String] match {
        case "Subscribe" =>
          val target = (msg \ "value").as[String]

          // Query database with Morphia
          val current = MyObj.findByName(target)

          // Notify of current state
          ws ! StatusUpdate(target, current)

          // Subscribe for further updates
          mediator ! DistributedPubSubMediator.Subscribe(target, ws)
      }
    }

    (in, out)
  }
}
```

The problem occurs in the query statement in the Iterattee. After a reload, Morphia throws
`org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Could not map models.MyObj with ID: 5507a3653004b8a9e8f3d3b2`. Here's the full trace:

```
org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Could not map models.MyObj with ID: 5507a3653004b8a9e8f3d3b2
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:594)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:299)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.convertItem(MorphiaIterator.java:79)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.processItem(MorphiaIterator.java:65)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.next(MorphiaIterator.java:60)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.get(QueryImpl.java:402)
    at models.MyObj$.findByName(MyObj.scala:99)
    at controllers.MyObj$$anonfun$MyObj$1$$anonfun$4.apply(MyObj.scala:99)
    at controllers.MyObj$$anonfun$MyObj$1$$anonfun$4.apply(MyObj.scala:93)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:201)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:201)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$fold$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:41)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.internal$.eagerFuture(package.scala:30)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$fold$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:41)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$fold$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:41)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:60)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:60)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Error setting value from converter (ObjectIdConverter) for models.MyObj.id to 5507a3653004b8a9e8f3d3b2
    at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.DefaultConverters.fromDBObject(DefaultConverters.java:137)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.ValueMapper.fromDBObject(ValueMapper.java:27)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:608)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:589)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.bson.types.ObjectId field models.MyObj.id to models.MyObj
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:758)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappedField.setFieldValue(MappedField.java:508)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.converters.DefaultConverters.fromDBObject(DefaultConverters.java:135)
    ... 27 more
```

This exception only happens in the web socket handler, regular request can make the query just fine. Fully restarting the development server fixes the problem until the next reload.

Here's the console logs from startup and one restart: http://pastebin.com/xsstw4ki

Any thoughts on what may be going on here? The other references I found to this error seem [unrelated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798572/findall-fails-after-play-morphia-is-reinitialised) or [old](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/morphia/dqiho9BQUFs).

### Update - July 4, 2015

Happens on Play 2.4.2 as well.

Comment: I posted a GitHub-issue (https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4557) and  following that a Google Groups entry (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/w0WhIckqvP0/6ZJ8_4KAKokJ) and still dead so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code snippet to resolve this. Modify your morphia creation by adding following code (Scala Code)

```
if (Play.isDev)
    morphia.getMapper.getOptions.setObjectFactory(new PlayCreator)
```

The definition for PlayCreator class is (Java Code)

```
public class PlayCreator extends DefaultCreator {

@Override
protected ClassLoader getClassLoaderForClass() {
    return Play.application().classloader();
}
}
```

Please add relevant imports and your hot reload should work great :)

Comment: This codebase is for Play 2.4.x. Use relevant methods for other versions of Play 2.x